# Updating a RealmRecyclerViewAdapter without updating DB

Tags: android, database, realm, realmrecyclerviewadapter

I am using `realm DB` for the first time. I am listing File info in recyclerview from `Realm results` using `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` . I need to update each item with its download progress, without writing the progress to DB. I am using android DownloadManager for that. How can I do that please help me.

Comment: You could have a `Map<PrimaryKey, Progress>` (with proper types) and update the views based on that?

Comment: you mean inside adapter ?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah

Comment: thanks a lot @EpicPandaForce. It worked for me.